# Set a background color to a zone defined by push pins set

Tags: c#, colors, polygon, bing-maps

I've defined a zone (by using DbGeography.PolygonFromText) delimited by a push pins set on a map.

I want to set a color to this zone.

How to do that ?

Comment: Which Bing Maps API are you overlaying this on top of?

Comment: Bing Maps WPF Control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since you are using the Bing Maps WPF control you must be turning the DbGeography object into a MapPolygon object, or a MapShapeBase object (base class of MapPolygon) somewhere in your code as the WPF control would not recognize the DbGeography object. Find where this is. Once you find this code you can set the Fill property of the MapPolygon object with a Brush to give it a color. Here is some documentation on the MapPolygon class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.mappolygon.aspx